# iTerm2: how to remove the right arrow before the cursor line

Tags: iterm2

Please look at the picture, It is a screenshot of iTerm2 Build 3.0.0

the blue arrow at the beginning of the cursor line. How to remove or hide it?

[image]

Comment: Those blue (and red) triangles are a part of shell integration, you could always remove shell integration: https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html

Comment: are you sure that's not your zsh theme ?

Comment: @sel-fish No, I did not install zsh

Answer (score 189, accepted):

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5088

> you can turn it off by going in to Preferences > Profiles > (your profile) > Terminal, scroll down to "Shell Integration", and turn off "Show mark indicators".

Comment: incase u have the issue of "iterm2 opens two window or two tabs when launched from services" check https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/6562#note_62569788

Answer (score 4):

Click on this option and disable

[image: Click this option and disable]