Turn off command highlighting in May 20 2024 iTerm2 Release
This highlighting feature is driving me crazy. How do I turn it off?


same haha, is a shitty feature TBH

This is so incredibly annoying that it made me migrate to Wezterm…

The feature is called "Selection" which can be turned off via the Settings/General/Selection menu.
Deselect the checkbox Clicking on a command selects it to restrict Find and Filter.


You can click a command to select it. Search,
Filter, and Select All will then be restricted
to the selected command. You can disable this
feature in Settings > General > Selection.



Release Notes




this answer should be marked as the right answer

BTW, how do I remove the > right chevron at the beginning of each command?

OK found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38913948/11705679

Thanks. I've been going through every setting and couldn't find it. It's an annoying feature that's on by default.
